# How to affect the maximizing area of other windows so that my AIR window is always shown?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to do in Adobe AIR (e.g. in ActionScript 3.0) what Facebook Messenger does when it's "maximized":

[image]

So imagine that I would be making a clone of this Facebook Messenger.

**Is this possible in Adobe AIR?**

I've tried to search in the AIR Reference with no success. And I don't even know what words to use in Google Search.

Comment: I believe the term you'd be wanting to google for is Docking, unfortunately trying to google for this I only found a post saying it's not possible, http://forums.adobe.com/thread/489808.  Good luck, hope there's a better answer than that forum.

Comment: Did some more searching just cause this ability of some programs has always escaped me, I found a bit more information on it and as I was assuming it requires a direct hand to the OS so it's probably not a simple thing to deliver cross platform (AIR) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3

Comment: There might be some way you can hack this if you just want windows compatibility by writing something in C# to send the signals for windows to resize everything else and invoke said C# executable using a native process in AIR, but from what I can tell it will be hacks on top of hacks on top of hacks and the ease of exporting for other platforms would be gone.

Comment: Hi Shaunhusain, thanks for those links. The link about C# looks really valuable, and also I'm starting get convinced that's there are no docking capabilities in Adobe AIR. This is ok by me, I wanted to know _before_ developing the app. Maybe C# and .NET might be a better platform for my situation (Windows-only app).

Comment: How about making your comments an answer?

Comment: okay posted it, sorry I have a tendency to do this on SO where I get interested and the comments slowly build to some sort of answer, I just don't like to answer in cases where I have no clear direction to a solution and believe someone else may be more likely to offer one if they see no answer.  Anyhow best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term I've heard used for this kind of feature is "Docking."  There seem to be a lot of front-end component libraries that offer this capability within a window (built in Flex or Java or C#, that I've seen).  However the ability to dock a window with regard to the OS view, where all other windows occupy the remaining area after an application is docked appears to require OS specific code to indicate to the operating system that the usable window space should change.  I've found no solution for this within AIR however did eventually find this link to some [C# code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3), intuition tells me this wasn't implemented in AIR because it was difficult to come up with a cross platform solution to the issue (not sure how easy this would be given the X windowing interface or other types of platforms they would have to deal with).

The options seem to be limited to working with C#, .NET, and/or windows forms (I believe this was formerly MFC, but I've been out of the Microsoft code world for quite a while).  You could potentially use a NativeProcess in AIR to spin off a C# exe that could send the signal to the OS but I have in no way proven this to be actually achievable, it just seems plausible, but would require further investigation and would definitely eliminate any cross platform capability offered by AIR.  If you're simply more comfortable working with Flex layouts/component sets and other features, you could start with the C# code for creating a docking area, this could branch down one of two paths then, attempt to spin up that process using a NativeProcess in AIR if that fails continue using .NET to build the remainder of the application.  If you were to go the AIR route packaging the C# exe with the AIR installation should be relatively trivial.